# FirestoreRecyclerAdapter not updating views

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I`m using FirestoreRecyclerAdapter and faced with the problem.

```
                Query query = db
                .collection(SOME_COLLECTION)
                .whereEqualTo("key", key)                    
                .orderBy("dueDate");
```

If I put orderBy, data loaded just first time. Real time updates not working. I tried putting orderBy at the end, as well as changing ordering fields.

If I remove orderBy, all works well. But no ordering.

According to documentation it should work when not using range comparison. Any ideas?

Updated. Here is adapter options.

```
             FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Payment> options = 
             new  FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Payment>()
            .setQuery(query, Payment.class)
            .build();
```

Here is Payment.

```
public class Payment {

private String key;
private double amount;
private Date cDate;
private Date paidDate;
private Date dueDate;
private boolean isPaid;

public Payment() {
}

Payment(String key, double amount, Date cDate, Date paidDate, Date dueDate, boolean isPaid) {
    this.key = key;
    this.amount = amount;
    this.cDate = cDate;
    this.paidDate = paidDate;
    this.dueDate = dueDate;
    this.isPaid = isPaid;
    }
}
```

Here is Payment Holder.

```
class PaymentHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

private TextView pDate, pAmount;
private CheckBox pDone;

PaymentHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    pDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pDate);
    pAmount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pAmount);
    pDone = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);


}}
```

And here is adapter.

```
firestoreRecyclerAdapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Payment, PaymentHolder>(options) {


        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(final PaymentHolder paymentHolder, final int position, final Payment payment) {

            final DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM);

            final String id = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getId();

            paymentHolder.getpDate().setText(dateFormat.format(payment.getDueDate()));
            paymentHolder.getpAmount().setText(getAmount(payment.getAmount()));
            paymentHolder.getpDone().setChecked(payment.isPaid());


        }


        @Override
        public PaymentHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

            View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.payment_item, viewGroup, false);

            final PaymentHolder paymentHolder = new PaymentHolder(view);

            return paymentHolder;
        }
    };

    recyclerView.setAdapter(firestoreRecyclerAdapter);
```

All set accorting to examples, nothing fancy.

Comment: The code you shared doesn't do anything with `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter`. It's hard to say what's going wrong without seeing the [minimal **complete** code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link, it's quite useful).

Comment: Do you have an index defined on that combination of fields? If not, you should get a pretty explicit warning in your logcat about out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Frank said, you should create index. If you look more precise at log, there is a warning and a link to create index. Just click on link and that is it. Big brother creates right index for you. Thank you Frank.